# Change field value based on another field with Ajax and c#

Tags: c#, ajax, formfield

I'm trying to create a page. It is very simple like when I change one textbox value, another one changes automatically without leaving the field. I used TextChanged event. But I have to leave the field to change another field value. Any help?

The aspx file :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The aspx.cs file :

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

I'm kinda newbie in aspx and c#. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

use event 'OnkeyPress' not 'OnTextChanged'

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best solved by KnockoutJS, AngularJS, jQuery, or simply Javascript

Comment: I think I have to use Ajax. Because it is not that simple, I just simplified it. I have to change the value based on another field value. All of the values of fields should populated from database.